# How can I delay one feed in wordpress but not the others?

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed, syndication-feed

Is there anyway to create a special feed in Wordpress that is on a delay that I can distribute to some of our content partners?  I have found some tutorials on how to delay your feed (http://wpengineer.com/publish-the-feed-later/) but it uses the conditional statement is_feed and I don't want to apply this to all feeds, just one particular feed.  Any advice?

Comment: On which feed do you need the delay? It is hard to offer a solution without this information.

Comment: True.  Sorry about that.  I guess the feed doesn't necessarily exist yet.  I need to have a full content feed that mirrors my sites normal feed but is just on a delay.  I will probably have to create a new feed for this but I am open to alternative suggestions.  Basically, the goal is to have one feed the distributes all published content on the site normally (for the readers), and have one that distributes the same content but does so on a delay (for our syndication partners).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the question answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1397/delaying-one-rss-feed-in-wordpress-but-not-the-others